# Array element evaluation from reverse

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm still very new to python and programing and I'm trying to figure out if I'm going about this problem in the correct fashion. I tend to have a matlab approach to things but here I'm just struggling...

Context:
I have two numpy arrays plotted in [this image on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/71501665@N07/6463960765/in/photostream) since I can't post photos here :(. They are of equal length properties (both 777x1600) and I'm trying to use the red array to help return the index(value on the x-axis of plot) and element value(y-axis) of the point in the blue plot indicated by the arrow for each row of the blue array.

The procedure I've been tasked with was to:
 a) determine max value of red array (represented with red dot in figure and already achieved)

and b) Start at the end of the blue array with the final element and count backwards, comparing element to preceding element. Goal being to determine where the preceding value decreases. (for example, when element -1 is greater than element -2, indicative of the last peak in the image). Additionally, to prevent selecting "noise" at the tail end of the section with elevated values, I also need to constrain the selected value to be larger than the maximum of the red array.

Here's what I've got so far, but I'm stuck on line two where I have to evaluate the selected row of the array from the (-1) position in the row to the beginning, or (0) position:

```
for i,n in enumerate(blue):  #select each row of blue in turn to analyze
    for j,m in enumerate(n):  #select each element of blue ??how do I start from the end of array and work backwards??
        if m > m-1 and m > max_val_red[i]:
        indx_m[i] = j
        val_m[i] = m
```

Comment: enumerate(n[::-1]) could work...
the list will be reversed but the index will start from 0 to n

Answer (score 2):

To answer you question directly, you can use n[::-1] to reverse the arrray n.

So the code is :

```
for j, m in enumerate(n[::-1]):
    j = len(n)-j-1
    # here is your code
```

But to increase calculation speed, you should avoid python loop:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([1,2,3,4,2,5,7,8,3,2,3,3,0,1,1,2])

idx = np.nonzero(np.diff(n) < 0)[0]
peaks = n[idx]
mask = peaks > 3 # peak muse larger than 3

print "index=", idx[mask]
print "value=", peaks[mask]
```

the output is:

```
index= [3 7]
value= [4 8]
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and I will keep the tip in mind when deadlines no longer loom. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean:

```
if m > n[j-1] and m > max_val_red[i]:
    indx_m[i] = j
    val_m[i] = m
```

because `m > m - 1` is always True

To reverse an array on an axis you can index the array using `::-1` on that axis, for example to reverse blue on axis 1 you can use:

```
blue_reverse = blue[:, ::-1]
```

Try and see you can write your function as a set of array operations instead of loops (that tends to be much faster). This is similar to the other answer, but it should allow you avoid both loops you're currently using:

```
threshold = red.max(1)
threshold = threshold[:, np.newaxis] #this makes threshold's shape (n, 1)

blue = blue[:, ::-1]
index_from_end = np.argmax((blue[:, :-1] > blue[:, 1:]) & (blue[:, :-1] > threshold), 1)
value = blue[range(len(blue)), index_from_end]
index = blue.shape[1] - 1 - index_from_end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't read all of it but you can possibly look into the built in function reversed. 
so instead of enumerate( n ). you can do reversed( enumerate( n ) ). But then your index would be wrong the correct index would be eval to len( n ) - j